# import mapclient ,and the error is that : TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-earth-engine, google-python-api

```
import ee
import mapclient
ee.Initialize()
image = ee.Image('srtm90_v4')
map = mapclient.MapClient()
map.addOverlay(mapclient.MakeOverlay(image.getMapId({'min': 0, 'max': 30})))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqHUX.jpg)
the error codes as follow:
Exception in thread Thread-9:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in **bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "mapclient.py", line 440, in run
        callback(image)
      File "mapclient.py", line 215, in AddTile
        newtile = ImageTk.PhotoImage(newtile)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 113, in __init**
        self.**photo = apply(Tkinter.PhotoImage, (), kw)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3367, in __init**
        Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3321, in **init**
        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
    TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
    Exception in thread Thread-7:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in **bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "mapclient.py", line 440, in run
        callback(image)
      File "mapclient.py", line 215, in AddTile
        newtile = ImageTk.PhotoImage(newtile)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 113, in __init**
        self.**photo = apply(Tkinter.PhotoImage, (), kw)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3367, in __init**
        Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3321, in **init**
        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
    TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
    Exception in thread Thread-16:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in **bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "mapclient.py", line 440, in run
        callback(image)
      File "mapclient.py", line 215, in AddTile
        newtile = ImageTk.PhotoImage(newtile)`enter code here`
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 113, in __init**
        self.**photo = apply(Tkinter.PhotoImage, (), kw)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3367, in __init**
        Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
      File "D:\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3321, in **init**
        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
        TclError: expected boolean value but got "??"

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm not using Anaconda or anything similar. Just the preinstalled Python in Linux. Python 2.7.12, linux Mint.

Comment: It can display the result as a picture at same time .If it can ,can you tell me  how to do that.